# Double ampersand in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am using the authlogic gem with Ruby on Rails, and I have been using the following to obtain the id of the user that is currently logged in:

```
current_user = UserSession.find
id = current_user && current_user.record.id
```

I'm not understanding how current_user && current_user.record.id returns the current user id. I would think this would return a boolean. Can someone explain how this works?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The logical and is short circuiting.  That means that if the construct is X && Y, and X is false then Y never gets checked because the whole thing is certainly going to be yield false.

That code is saying, essentially:

```
if (current_user is TRUE) {
    id = current_user.record.id;
]
```

Here's some console output showing you get the second value if the first is true:

```
irb(main):005:0> true && 9
=> 9
```

and nil if the first is nil:

```
irb(main):008:0> nil && 9
=> nil
```

Comment: Interesting. In PHP and some other languages, I've often used booleanValue = booleanExpression1 && booleanExpression2, and based on the evaluation of the "and" expression, booleanValue will be set appropriately. So this is not possible with Ruby?

Comment: PHP and other C-likes short-circuit their &&s too.  When you're using booleans the results are as you'd expect, but when you've got object types and dynamic types you're into the language specific zone.

Comment: Also, if X (current_user) is false (I assume this means current_user is not set--nil?), then will id be set to false rather than an int (the value of current_user.record.id)?

Comment: See my edit.  If current_user is nill the whole statement ends up as nil.

Comment: Really this has nothing to do with short circuiting; in Ruby, Perl, and other dynamic languages, the language designers chose `&&` to return the first false-ish value (or the last value, if all are true-ish), and `||` to return the first true-ish value (or the last value, if all are false-ish).  Short-circuiting just means that it stops at that return point, but even without short-circuiting the return value would be the same.

Comment: Ah, okay, I have seen the || symbol in Ruby before. That helps. On a different note, I don't think this works the same way in PHP. See this script, which prints 1, not 23: http://chadjohnson.ath.cx:8080/static/double_ampersand_test.phps

Comment: Yeah, PHP got it wrong.  Python gets it right, though their operators are called `and` and `or` -- which also work in Perl and Ruby, just with different precedences.

Comment: Chad, it's about short circuiting only because no one would use the patter if if weren't for short circuiting.  That line is safe because you're protected from trying to access .record.id on a nil current_user _because_ of the short circuiting.

Answer (score 22):

There is no `Boolean` type in Ruby; Ruby has a rather simple view of truth (or more precisely, it has a rather simple view of *falsehood*).

- the `false` object, which is the singleton instance of `FalseClass` is considered **falsy**
- the `nil` object, which is the singleton instance of `NilClass` is **falsy**
- *every other object* is **truthy** (including, obviously, the `true` object, which is the singleton instance of `TrueClass`)

[BTW: this means that a lot of objects that are considered **falsy** in some other languages, are actually **truthy** in Ruby, like the integer `0`, the real value `0.0`, the empty string, the empty array, the empty hash, the character `'F'`]

So, the Boolean operators `&&`, `||`, `and` and `or` *do not* return Boolean values. Instead they return *the first object that determines the outcome of the expression*.

(They are also short-circuiting, which means that they only evaluate the minimum sub-expressions that are needed to determine the outcome of the expression. So, an alternate formulation would be that they return the result of the last expression that was evaluated. Which, in turn, is analogous to what blocks, methods, class bodies and module bodies do.)

So, what does it *mean* to return the first object that determines the outcome? That's simple, really: the result of the expression

```
 a && b
```

is **truthy** if *both* `a` and `b` are **truthy**, otherwise it is **falsy**. So, if `a` is **falsy**, it is *completely* irrelevant what `b` is: the result will be **falsy** either way. So, we might just as well simply return `a`. (Remember, a doesn't have to be `false`, it could also be `nil` and the programmer might want to know which one of the two it was.)

If, OTOH, `a` is **truthy** (IOW it is neither `nil` nor `false`), then the result of the whole expression is *solely* dependent on `b`: if `b` is **truthy**, the whole result will be **truthy**, otherwise if `b` is **falsy**, the whole result will be **falsy**. So, we might just as well return `b` itself, instead of first converting it to a Boolean.

`||` and `or` are analogous or more precisely *dual* to `&&` and `and`.

You posted this example:

```
id = current_user && current_user.record.id
```

Here, the author isn't even *expecting* `current_user` to be a Boolean value! Instead, he expects it to be either a `User` or `nil`. But that's perfectly fine, because a `User` is **truthy** and `nil` is **falsy**, so they still can be used in a Boolean expression.

The basic intention is that the author wants to prevent a `NoMethodError` exception being raised, if he tries to call `#record` on `nil`.

An alternative way of expressing this would be

```
id = current_user.record.id unless current_user.nil?
```

If you want all the gory details, check out Section 11.1 (page 36) of the [Draft ISO Ruby Specification](http://ruby-std.netlab.jp/draft_spec/draft_ruby_spec-20091201-hl.pdf) or the excutable specifications of the [RubySpec project](http://RubySpec.Org/). ([Here's the one for `&&`](https://GitHub.Com/RubySpec/RubySpec/blob/master/language/and_spec.rb).)

I wrote a [pure Ruby implementation of Ruby's Boolean operators and conditional expressions](http://JoergWMittag.GitHub.Com/b001e/) once for fun. The meat of the implementations is these [two](https://GitHub.Com/JoergWMittag/b001e/blob/master/lib/b001e/falsiness.rb) [mixins](https://GitHub.Com/JoergWMittag/b001e/blob/master/lib/b001e/truthiness.rb).

Comment: this could be a blog entry :)

Comment: @Dty: It *is*. I just don't have a blog ;-)

Comment: örg: mind if i ask what you do for a living if you're not a "programmer"? You seem to know an awful lot for a "recreational" programmer! ps. wish there was a way to send IM's on SO.