# && Using the Ternary Operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey I was following Michael Hartl's railstutorial when I stumbled upon this chunk of code.

Does anyone have an idea what the "user &&" is used for by the ternary operator?

Here's the code:

```
def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
  user = find_by_email(email)
  user && user.has_password?(submitted_password) ? user : nil
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Double ampersand in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987955/double-ampersand-in-ruby)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&&` is a logical `and` except that it has a higher precedence than `and`. So the statement just says if user isn't nil and user has that password then return user, else return nil.

In Ruby, the second part of a logical and isn't executed if the first part is false. So the purpose here is to make sure there's a user before calling `has_password?` on it, thus preventing the error of calling `has_password?` on `nil`. Another way to do this would be to use `try`, e.g.:

```
user.try(:has_password?, submitted_password) ? user : nil
```

Comment: Nice thing to know: the concept of skipping part of a logical expression based on the value of an argument is called [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Always be careful regarding parts of an expression that might have side-effects which could be skipped this way. That is, avoid those entirely.

Answer (score 1):

It simply checks if `user` has any value before applying the method `has_password?` on it.